# Monitor spring web application on cloudfoundry

Tags: monitoring, cloud-foundry, btrace

I intend to monitor execution times of methods in a spring web application deployed on cloudfoundry.

I tried to integrate BTrace with the application during deployment but it didn't work.

Is there any tool which will help?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Spring Insight on Cloud Foundry: http://insight.cloudfoundry.com/

From their FAQ:

> Insight is a byte-code instrumentation monitoring tool for development and production. It is designed to provide light-weight visibility into the operation of a user's application and enable applications to more easily transition into production.